# How to Debug SpriteKit Forces

Tags: sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

In my SpriteKit train game, sometimes I get a strange behaviour. Most of the time everything works fine. But sometimes the engine sprite gets an impulse, so it moves out of the tracks.

[image: Out of tracks]

I checked my entire code if there are some applyForce(), etc. But the impulse comes from SpriteKit, but I don't know why.

Is there a possibility to debug SKPhysicsBodys so that I can identify the cause of the impulse?

Comment: I think is not possible to debug exactly that, but you can add a custom breakpoint on update() and check what is exactly happening on the scene when the train moves out of the tracks, also you can add some SKConstraint on the train to tracks.